# TLS handshake error only when I connect by phone using mobile data

Tags: go, ssl

I have a webpage containing a javascripted form which ask a server writen in golang for a json result.

Using the mobile phone to access that webpage I have noticed that whenever I connect through to it by data mobile only, 
the server responds with TLS handshake error, but when I use WIFI, the server behaves as expected.

Webpage is found at https://www.printuridigital.ro/colantare#calcul
`server.go:3055: http: TLS handshake error from 178.138.34.164:36503: read tcp 167.172.161.137:2000->178.138.34.164:36503: i/o timeout`

Comment: The error message is clear. The reason is a timeout. It could be too slow or it doesn't even get through. Do you have a firewall ? Have you tried a transaction between the mobile device and the server by using a simple HTTP request ? Does it get through ? Is it slow ?

Comment: Yes there is ufw in place but server is allowed. Other simple endpoint https://packong.ro:2000/api/v1/health accessed by phone using only data mobile works.

Comment: Do you have the problem only with mobile phone or also with another conventional device

Comment: When phone uses a WIFI connection it works. Only when it runs on its data mobile connection. And I was wrong about the simple endpoint. It doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried connecting to https://www.printuridigital.ro/colantare#calcul and saw no problem. I tried with a fixed connection network and with my mobile phone. So the cause must be related your mobile phone network. Note that I'm in France

Comment: Website is fine, it has a javascript that access an api, the endpoint https://packong.ro:2000/api/v1 has the issue. I believe culprit here is the way that server negotiates with the client represented by my javascript.

Comment: The aforementioned Issue has gone after I've changed port connection. Still have no clue why, but I can imagine somehow that port (:2000) was used.

Comment: it may by that the mobile phone operator filters some ports. I have seen such behavior with paranoid network operators.